# How to write a function that takes 3 int arguments and returns the largest of the 3?

Tags: c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int Function(int a, int b, int c)
    {
int Num;
    if(Num > a && Num > b)
return c;
    }

    int main()
    {



    return 0;
     system("PAUSE");
    }
```

// I'm totally clueless how to continue and what I have is correct.
I am unsure how to connect the function with main and how to use different variables to connect them, as well as what variables and calculations to put in main.

Comment: What comparaisons, or series of camparaisons, do you think would be necessary? Work it out on paper, then got to code.

Comment: In the case that this is not a joke, I suggest you take a look at a tutorial such as this one [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/)

Answer (score 0):

```
int Function(int a, int b, int c)   
{ 
    if ( a > b && a > c )
        return a;
    else if ( b > a && b > c )
        return b;
    else if ( c > a && c > b )
        return c;
}
```

I hope you know how to call this function in main(). Try doing some basic C coding tutorials, you will be able to do this quite easily.

Comment: That's long-winded: `int Function(int a, int b, int c) { int max = a; if (b > max) max = b; if (c > max) max = x; return max; }`.